# How to speed up $gt cursor on indexed field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

**Use Case:** Go through an entire collection, sorted by a key, to make computations. Since the run time is long, we are running it multiple times, carrying forward using `$gt` on the key.

**Query**
Below is a log entry from a cursor on a query like below:

```
{ mpn_alnum: { "$gt" : "ABCD" } }
```

**Log Output**

Formatted for readability on Stack Overflow:

```
command iodparts.searches command: 
  getMore {
    getMore: 259896659504,
    collection: "searches",
    $db: "iodparts",
    lsid: {
        id: UUID("XXXXXXXXXX")
    }
  }
  originatingCommand: {
    find: "searches",
    filter: {
        mpn_alnum: {
            $gt: "8051"
        }
    },
    sort: {
        mpn_alnum: 1
    },
    $db: "iodparts",
    lsid: {
        id: UUID("XXXXXXX")
    }
  }
  planSummary: IXSCAN {
    mpn_alnum: 1
  }
  cursorid: XXXXXXXX keysExamined: 184421 docsExamined: 184421 numYields: 2694 nreturned: 184420 reslen: 16777182 locks: {
    Global: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 5390
        }
    },
    Database: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 2695
        }
    },
    Collection: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 2695
        }
    }
  }
  protocol:op_msg 49796ms
```

1. The highest number of documents for the same `mpn_alnum` is 5000. Typically, they are less than 1000.
2. The number of documents in search collection is 27 million.

**Question**
This is taking 50-60 seconds each time to retrieve. Is there a way to improve the logic or speed up the operation?

**Update 1**

Clarifications:

"running it multiple times" means both: (a) fetched results from cursor for a few minutes. saved the last value of the returned field. (b) In the next query, picked up from where left, using $gt query. This one seems to take quite longer. The log output is output of getMore operation on one such query.

MongoDB Version: 3.6

WiredTiger is the engine.

**Update 2**

I used three different strategies that helped me get out of this issue.

A. Upgraded from MongoDB 3.6 to MongoDB 4.0

B. Doubled SDD Size and IOPS (I/O Operations per Second) - as per AWS EC2 standards - from 200 GB to 400 GB. The database was nearing 190+ GB.

C. Rewrote programming code from PHP 7 to NodeJS

Now, all the operations are under 1s. So its nearly 50X gain!

Comment: Is this using the WiredTiger engine?

Comment: When you say you are "running it multiple times" and carrying the parameter forward, what do you mean? Are you using a cursor and calling `next` on it, or are you just looking at the latest returned value and looking for values after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `keysExamined: 184421 docsExamined: 184421 numYields: 2694 nreturned: 184420`

This line suggests that the batch size is rather large. The default batch size for a mongo cursor is 100 documents, and when that's set, the logs should instead look something like `keysExamined: 102 docsExamined: 101 numYields: 8 nreturned: 101`. That way, it's not waiting to find 200k documents before being able to start processing.

A cursor based pseudo-code solution that iterates through a cursor and processes documents with the same group id might look something like this:

```js
const cursor = collection.find({mpn_alnum: {$gte: x}, {batchSize: 100});
let docs = [];
for await (const doc of cursor) {
 if (docs.length && doc.mpn_alnum !== docs[0].mpn_alnum) {
   await processBatch(docs);
   docs = [];
 }
 docs.push(doc);
}
```

Alternatively, mongo's [aggregation pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) are fast for processing data, and might be a better fit.

Comment: Voila!! So true. All of my current log statements now says docsExamined as 1000! And, that is how it is faster. I dont know if it is upgrade to 4.0 that fixed it or rewriting the code to NodeJS. I did not use batchSize by myself.

Comment: Awesome! Switching to the node-client should be what did it -- it has a default batch size of 1000 (https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/e5b762c6d53afa967f24c26a1d1b6c921757c9c9/lib/cursor/cursor.js#L136). I guess the php client doesn't have a default batch-size or does something else strange